# Pyspark Structured streaming locally with Kafka-Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

After looking at the other answers i still cant figure it out.

I am able to use kafkaProducer and kafkaConsumer to send and receive a messages from within my notebook.

```
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('hr',bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],group_id='abc' )
```

I've tried to connect to the stream with both spark context and spark session.

```
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
    sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "stream")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
```

Which gives me this error

```
    Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one 
    of the following.

    1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
    spark-submit command as

    $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming- 
    kafka-0-8:2.3.2 ...
```

It seems that i needed to add the JAR to my

```
    !/usr/local/bin/spark-submit   --master local[*]  /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.2.jar pyspark-shell
```

which returns

```
    Error: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class
    Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

What class do i put in?
How do i get Pyspark to connect to the consumer?

Comment: Are you giving the package as `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

The command you have is trying to *run* `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.2.jar`, and trying to find `pyspark-shell` as a Java class inside of that.

As the first error says, you missed a `--packages` after `spark-submit`, which means you would do

```
spark-submit --packages ... someApp.jar com.example.YourClass
```

---

If you are just locally in Jupyter, you may want to try Kafka-Python, for example, rather than PySpark... Less overhead, and no Java dependencies.

Comment: @mayank agrawal    !/usr/local/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.3.2 pyspark-shell  returns                                 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH

Comment: Not sure about that, but it's unrelated to Kafka. Your code is probably similar to this https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/

Comment: I saw that blog. When i try to run the KafkaUtils.createStream command i get the "Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one 
    of the following." Error response

Comment: That `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']` line seems to suggest otherwise. It is adding the package within the code. In your error, you missed `--packages`, as mentioned